# Why does my code work from interactive shell, but not when run from a file?

Tags: python, python-module, pprint, python-interactive

I am trying to use the `pprint` module to check out some vars in Python, which I can happily do using the interactive shell and the code below:

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
stuff = ['cakes','bread','mead']
pp.pprint(stuff)
```

However, when I put the above into `pprint.py` and run it using `python pprint.py` I get the error:

```
$ python dev/pars/pprint.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dev/pars/pprint.py", line 1, in ?
    import pprint
  File "/home/origina2/dev/pars/pprint.py", line 2, in ?
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PrettyPrinter'
```

What is different about the way modules are called when running Python code from a file compared to the interactive shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You named your program pprint.py, so at the line `import pprint` it tries to import itself.  It succeeds, but *your* pprint.py doesn't contain anything called PrettyPrinter.

Change your code's name.  [And, to be clear, delete any pprint.pyc or pprint.pyo files..]

Comment: i copied your code exactly into a file called `test.py` and it runs with no problem. Do you have issues with other python modules? Maybe a reinstall would help?

Comment: Ok, try copying it into pprint.py, running it, then renaming the file and running it again :)